# DB restriction PG ADMIN4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am having 15 databases and some users. What happens is when the users are getting logged in they can see the other databases details like(schema, table names etc). They themselves can use the DB restriction feature. Is there any solution that it can be restricted from the admin end so that they don't see any other databases which they don't have access to them when they logged in?

Comment: You can't solve this problem because it doesn't exist in the first place, at least not as described.  They can see the names of other databases, but they can't see the schema names or table names for databases they can't connect to.

Comment: In my case the person can see the schema also since its on same server

Comment: Being on the same server doesn't matter.  Please show what it is you are looking at which makes you think this is happening.